# After installing .NET Core 1.1.0 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview in Visual Studio 2015 community update 3, I donot see .Net Core template

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

After installing .NET Core 1.1.0 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview in Visual Studio 2015 community update 3, I don't see .Net Core template

I uninstalled the previous Visual Studio 2015 community update 3 and .Net Core 1.0 with TotalUninstaller tool from Git. The uninstall process was successful.

Then I've reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 community update 3 and .NET Core 1.1.0 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview. When I create a new project, I don't see .Net Core in the templates. I also have Web Developer Tools installed. I've followed advises on other blogs Am I missing something? Thanks.

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Have you installed the Visual Studio 2015 Tools (Preview 2)? https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=827546

Comment: Hi Adrian, you're awesome!!! Thanks very much. I followed your advice... installed the Visual Studio 2015 Tools (Preview 2), reinstalled .NET Core 1.1.0 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview, then ran the repair on Visual Studio 2015 Tools. I'm able to create .Net Core project now. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that worked. No problem.